# What would be a good approach to replace {mySection} type tags using Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC3, C# and Razor.

I have template paragraghs, which are stored and edited in the DB, like

"The sales data can be shown as follows: {SalesTable1}"

I would wish to substitute the {SalesTable1} bit with the result of some code(most likely razor) that iterates through the "Sales" class, ie

```
<table>
@foreach var item in Sales
{
 <tr>
 <td>@item.Product</td>
 <td>@item.Sales</td>
 </tr>
}
</table>
```

Code above may be not quite right, but it shows the idea.

In XSLT one would call a "template" with say a name of "SalesTable1".

What would be a good approach to solving this in Razor? BTW I am using a ViewModel where I can put my template data and my real data for processing by my View.

Thanks.

EDIT: I do not need {MySection} type tags(specifically) in the template if there is a better way of doing it. However it is important that "Admins" can edit the text around these tags within the application.

EDIT2: I have a main View which calls different Partial Views depending on different topic types. Within each Partial View I am hoping to replace the {tags} with the runtime @section templates which are also specificied in the Partial View. This seems not to work. I guess because "RenderSection" commands should appear in the Layout or parent View.

EDIT3: I think I would be better off using another RenderPartial from my Partial View. However I am unsure how I would replace the {myTable} tag with @{Html.RenderPartial("myTable");}.

```
<text>This is a test sentence. {myTable} After table </text>
```

to produce:

```
 <text>This is a test sentence. @{Html.RenderPartial("myTable");} After table </text>
```

Finally I do have one issue with this approach in that if the "myTable" partial does not exist, or the {myTable} is misspelled ie {MyTablee} then the application would crash. I would want it to just carry on without running the Partial View.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MVC3 Sections... they are defined as follows..

```
@section SideBar {
 // Side bar code...
}
```

then when you need to render them, you simply call

```
@RenderSection("SideBar");
```

There is a great post by the GU here...

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this. However I am not sure it will solve my problem since I have a main view which then render Partial Views. The logic that controls the "RenderSection" commands exist in the Partial Views. It seems that Partial Views cannot be called that contain "RenderSection" commands. Perhaps this is because "RenderSection" is a top level command and can only be in the layout View? More details in "Edit" above.

Comment: I have added further comments in EDIT3 describing further thoughts. Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: Marked up as appreciated the help, although  not the answer to my problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this now by using replacing the tags for Partial Views.

Many thanks.